# Windows build for PyLucene+JCC on python 2.6

Tags: python, windows, pylucene, jcc

Where can I download a PyLucene+JCC Windows build compiled for python 2.6?

Jose

Comment: God knows I'd love one of these too!  PyLucene and JCC are awfully hard to build in my experience.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and interfacing it using XML/JSON.

Comment: We did this too. Found it to be the path of least resistance by far!

Answer (score 2):

Not tested but there appears to be an egg here:

http://code.google.com/p/pylucene-win32-binary/

Answer (score 1):

you might want to see [this recent mailing list post](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-pylucene-dev/200902.mbox/%3Calpine.OSX.2.00.0902181122530.1109@yuzu.local%3E)  and the related thread. There's also a [pylucene-dev](http://markmail.org/message/d6tfni5sdqywwfoy) thread that seems apropos. Unfortunately, none of these things have what you want; you'll still have to build it yourself.

If you're really feeling charitable, you can publish the steps + binaries once you figure it out, but I don't know.